# Hide woocommerce login form

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

Im trying to hide the woocommerce login form on certian pages with code but i cant seem to get it to work
here is what we have

```
  add_action( 'woocommerce_login_form', 'woocom_extra_register_fields');
 
function woocom_extra_register_fields (){
        if(is_page('installation')){
            remove_action('woocommerce_login_form', 10 );
    }
}
```

Comment: Check answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55477637/591486

Answer (score -1):

You miss the required `remove_action()` parameter — the name of the function to remove. See the [Code Reference](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/remove_action/).

```
<?php

add_action( 'woocommerce_login_form', 'woocom_extra_register_fields' );

function woocom_extra_register_fields () {
    if ( is_page( 'installation' ) ) {
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_login_form', 'woocom_extra_register_fields', 10 ); // note this
    }
}
```

I suspect the code you've posted is not complete, so, adding the action to remove the action itself looks odd. Simplify things to avoid superfluous operations:

```
<?php

add_action( 'woocommerce_login_form', 'woocom_extra_register_fields' );

function woocom_extra_register_fields () {
    // check you are NOT on the 'installation' page
    if ( ! is_page( 'installation' ) ) {

        // do your extra fields here

    }
}
```